# Display only one marker for multiple occurrence of same lat-longs from array but show data of these occurrences in infowindow

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have an array which is in the format given below:

```
jarray = [
 {"Latitude":"17.3750688888889","Longitude":"78.4824888888889","Speed":"13","TrackTime":"08-Feb-19 11:11:10 AM"},
 {"Latitude":"17.3750688888889","Longitude":"78.4824888888889","Speed":"13","TrackTime":"08-Feb-19 11:12:33 AM"},
 {"Latitude":"17.3746811111111","Longitude":"78.4825511111111","Speed":"0","TrackTime":"08-Feb-19 11:12:33 AM"},
 {"Latitude":"17.3746811111111","Longitude":"78.4825511111111","Speed":"0","TrackTime":"08-Feb-19 11:12:35 AM"},
 {"Latitude":"17.3746811111111","Longitude":"78.4825511111111","Speed":"0","TrackTime":"08-Feb-19 11:18:00 AM"},
 {"Latitude":"17.3746811111111","Longitude":"78.4825511111111","Speed":"0","TrackTime":"08-Feb-19 11:23:30 AM"},
 {"Latitude":"17.3747333333333","Longitude":"78.4824977777778","Speed":"8","TrackTime":"08-Feb-19 11:27:29 AM"},
 {"Latitude":"17.3747866666667","Longitude":"78.48232","Speed":"16","TrackTime":"08-Feb-19 11:27:29 AM"},
 {"Latitude":"17.3747366666667","Longitude":"78.4821244444444","Speed":"11","TrackTime":"08-Feb-19 11:27:29 AM"},
 {"Latitude":"17.3746","Longitude":"78.4819022222222","Speed":"7","TrackTime":"08-Feb-19 11:27:29 AM"},
 {"Latitude":"17.3746433333333","Longitude":"78.4818044444444","Speed":"17","TrackTime":"08-Feb-19 11:27:29 AM"},
 {"Latitude":"17.3748111111111","Longitude":"78.4816088888889","Speed":"10","TrackTime":"08-Feb-19 11:27:29 AM"},
 {"Latitude":"17.3748111111111","Longitude":"78.4816088888889","Speed":"10","TrackTime":"08-Feb-19 11:27:30 AM"},
 {"Latitude":"17.3747388888889","Longitude":"78.4816177777778","Speed":"10","TrackTime":"08-Feb-19 11:27:37 AM"},
 {"Latitude":"17.3743955555556","Longitude":"78.482","Speed":"8","TrackTime":"08-Feb-19 11:27:57 AM"},
 {"Latitude":"17.3743111111111","Longitude":"78.4821244444444","Speed":"0","TrackTime":"08-Feb-19 11:28:40 AM"}
];
```

I need to show markers using google maps api based on above array only at lat-longs where speed is 0. Markers should also have onclick infowindow where it should display first TimeStamp, last TimeStamp and duration between both timestamps.

Update1: As per previous comments, I have tried to replicate part of my code.. So these are my efforts:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Halting Points</title>
  <style>
    /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
    
    #map {
      height: 100%;
    }
    /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
    
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <script>
    function initMap() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 5,
        center: {
          lat: 17.3850,
          lng: 78.4867
        },
        mapTypeId: 'terrain'
      });
      var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
      var jarray = [
      {"Latitude":"17.3750688888889","Longitude":"78.4824888888889","Speed":"13","TrackTime":"08-Feb-19 11:11:10 AM"},
      {"Latitude":"17.3750688888889","Longitude":"78.4824888888889","Speed":"13","TrackTime":"08-Feb-19 11:12:33 AM"},
      {"Latitude":"17.3746811111111","Longitude":"78.4825511111111","Speed":"0","TrackTime":"08-Feb-19 11:12:33 AM"},
      {"Latitude":"17.3746811111111","Longitude":"78.4825511111111","Speed":"0","TrackTime":"08-Feb-19 11:12:35 AM"},
      {"Latitude":"17.3746811111111","Longitude":"78.4825511111111","Speed":"0","TrackTime":"08-Feb-19 11:18:00 AM"},
      {"Latitude":"17.3746811111111","Longitude":"78.4825511111111","Speed":"0","TrackTime":"08-Feb-19 11:23:30 AM"},
      {"Latitude":"17.3747333333333","Longitude":"78.4824977777778","Speed":"8","TrackTime":"08-Feb-19 11:27:29 AM"},
      {"Latitude":"17.3747866666667","Longitude":"78.48232","Speed":"16","TrackTime":"08-Feb-19 11:27:29 AM"},
      {"Latitude":"17.3747366666667","Longitude":"78.4821244444444","Speed":"11","TrackTime":"08-Feb-19 11:27:29 AM"},
      {"Latitude":"17.3746","Longitude":"78.4819022222222","Speed":"7","TrackTime":"08-Feb-19 11:27:29 AM"},
      {"Latitude":"17.3746433333333","Longitude":"78.4818044444444","Speed":"17","TrackTime":"08-Feb-19 11:27:29 AM"},
      {"Latitude":"17.3748111111111","Longitude":"78.4816088888889","Speed":"10","TrackTime":"08-Feb-19 11:27:29 AM"},
      {"Latitude":"17.3748111111111","Longitude":"78.4816088888889","Speed":"10","TrackTime":"08-Feb-19 11:27:30 AM"},
      {"Latitude":"17.3747388888889","Longitude":"78.4816177777778","Speed":"10","TrackTime":"08-Feb-19 11:27:37 AM"},
      {"Latitude":"17.3743955555556","Longitude":"78.482","Speed":"8","TrackTime":"08-Feb-19 11:27:57 AM"},
      {"Latitude":"17.3743111111111","Longitude":"78.4821244444444","Speed":"0","TrackTime":"08-Feb-19 11:28:40 AM"}
      ];
      var pointstat = [];
      var tracktimearray;
      var flightPlanCoordinates = [];
      for (i = 0; i <
        jarray.length; i++) {
        flightPlanCoordinates[i] = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(jarray[i].Latitude), parseFloat(jarray[i].Longitude));
        if (jarray[i].Speed == "0") {
          var tracktime = (jarray[i].TrackTime);
          var fli = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(jarray[i].Latitude), parseFloat(jarray[i].Longitude));
          addhaltmarker(fli, tracktime);
        }
      }

      function addhaltmarker(fli, tracktime) {
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: tracktime
        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: fli,
          map: map
        });
        marker.addListener('click', function() {
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
      }

      for (i = 0; i <
        flightPlanCoordinates.length; i++) {
        bounds.extend(flightPlanCoordinates[i]);
      }
      var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: flightPlanCoordinates,
        geodesic: true,
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 2
      });
      flightPath.setMap(map);

      map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }
  </script>
  <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=KEY&callback=initMap"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Above code draws a polyline as per the data, creates marker at positions where speed is '0', shows onclick infowindow with TimeStamp as content.

Technically the code is spawning multiple markers on same location and displays timestamp of last marker but what I need to achieve is, it should spawn only one marker and show both start and end Timestamps as well as duration of speed status 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. for each marker process through the list of points, finding instances of the same point.

```
for (var i = 0; i < jarray.length; i++) {
  if (!jarray[i].latLng)
    jarray[i].latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(jarray[i].Latitude, jarray[i].Longitude);
  if (google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(fli, jarray[i].latLng) < 1) {
    var obj = jarray[i];
    obj.timestamp = Date.parse(obj.TrackTime);
    duplicatePoints.push(obj);
  }
}
```

2. sort those points by time.

```
duplicatePoints.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.timestamp - b.timestamp
});
```

3. add the first and last times; and the duration to the `InfoWindow`

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: tracktime + "<br>first time:" + duplicatePoints[0].TrackTime +
    "<br>last time:" + duplicatePoints[duplicatePoints.length - 1].TrackTime +
    "<br>duration:" + ((duplicatePoints[duplicatePoints.length - 1].timestamp - duplicatePoints[0].timestamp) / 60 / 1000).toFixed(2) + " minutes"
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/keatr60L/4/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

```js
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 5,
    center: {
      lat: 17.3850,
      lng: 78.4867
    },
    mapTypeId: 'terrain'
  });
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  var pointstat = [];
  var tracktimearray;
  var flightPlanCoordinates = [];
  for (i = 0; i <
    jarray.length; i++) {
    flightPlanCoordinates[i] = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(jarray[i].Latitude), parseFloat(jarray[i].Longitude));
    if (jarray[i].Speed == "0") {
      var tracktime = (jarray[i].TrackTime);
      var fli = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(jarray[i].Latitude), parseFloat(jarray[i].Longitude));
      addhaltmarker(fli, tracktime);
    }
  }

  function addhaltmarker(fli, tracktime) {
    var duplicatePoints = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < jarray.length; i++) {
      if (!jarray[i].latLng)
        jarray[i].latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(jarray[i].Latitude, jarray[i].Longitude);
      if (google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(fli, jarray[i].latLng) < 1) {
        var obj = jarray[i];
        obj.timestamp = Date.parse(obj.TrackTime);
        duplicatePoints.push(obj);
      }
    }
    duplicatePoints.sort(function(a, b) {
      return a.timestamp - b.timestamp
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: tracktime + "<br>first time:" + duplicatePoints[0].TrackTime +
        "<br>last time:" + duplicatePoints[duplicatePoints.length - 1].TrackTime +
        "<br>duration:" + ((duplicatePoints[duplicatePoints.length - 1].timestamp - duplicatePoints[0].timestamp) / 60 / 1000).toFixed(2) + " minutes"
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: fli,
      map: map
    });
    marker.addListener('click', function() {
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
  }

  for (i = 0; i <
    flightPlanCoordinates.length; i++) {
    bounds.extend(flightPlanCoordinates[i]);
  }
  var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: flightPlanCoordinates,
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2
  });
  flightPath.setMap(map);

  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
var jarray = [{
    "Latitude": "17.3750688888889",
    "Longitude": "78.4824888888889",
    "Speed": "13",
    "TrackTime": "08-Feb-19 11:11:10 AM"
  },
  {
    "Latitude": "17.3750688888889",
    "Longitude": "78.4824888888889",
    "Speed": "13",
    "TrackTime": "08-Feb-19 11:12:33 AM"
  },
  {
    "Latitude": "17.3746811111111",
    "Longitude": "78.4825511111111",
    "Speed": "0",
    "TrackTime": "08-Feb-19 11:12:33 AM"
  },
  {
    "Latitude": "17.3746811111111",
    "Longitude": "78.4825511111111",
    "Speed": "0",
    "TrackTime": "08-Feb-19 11:12:35 AM"
  },
  {
    "Latitude": "17.3746811111111",
    "Longitude": "78.4825511111111",
    "Speed": "0",
    "TrackTime": "08-Feb-19 11:18:00 AM"
  },
  {
    "Latitude": "17.3746811111111",
    "Longitude": "78.4825511111111",
    "Speed": "0",
    "TrackTime": "08-Feb-19 11:23:30 AM"
  },
  {
    "Latitude": "17.3747333333333",
    "Longitude": "78.4824977777778",
    "Speed": "8",
    "TrackTime": "08-Feb-19 11:27:29 AM"
  },
  {
    "Latitude": "17.3747866666667",
    "Longitude": "78.48232",
    "Speed": "16",
    "TrackTime": "08-Feb-19 11:27:29 AM"
  },
  {
    "Latitude": "17.3747366666667",
    "Longitude": "78.4821244444444",
    "Speed": "11",
    "TrackTime": "08-Feb-19 11:27:29 AM"
  },
  {
    "Latitude": "17.3746",
    "Longitude": "78.4819022222222",
    "Speed": "7",
    "TrackTime": "08-Feb-19 11:27:29 AM"
  },
  {
    "Latitude": "17.3746433333333",
    "Longitude": "78.4818044444444",
    "Speed": "17",
    "TrackTime": "08-Feb-19 11:27:29 AM"
  },
  {
    "Latitude": "17.3748111111111",
    "Longitude": "78.4816088888889",
    "Speed": "10",
    "TrackTime": "08-Feb-19 11:27:29 AM"
  },
  {
    "Latitude": "17.3748111111111",
    "Longitude": "78.4816088888889",
    "Speed": "10",
    "TrackTime": "08-Feb-19 11:27:30 AM"
  },
  {
    "Latitude": "17.3747388888889",
    "Longitude": "78.4816177777778",
    "Speed": "10",
    "TrackTime": "08-Feb-19 11:27:37 AM"
  },
  {
    "Latitude": "17.3743955555556",
    "Longitude": "78.482",
    "Speed": "8",
    "TrackTime": "08-Feb-19 11:27:57 AM"
  },
  {
    "Latitude": "17.3743111111111",
    "Longitude": "78.4821244444444",
    "Speed": "0",
    "TrackTime": "08-Feb-19 11:28:40 AM"
  }
];
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90%;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&libraries=geometry&callback=initMap"></script>
```